# Syntax when calling an array as the variable in a new block of code? [C]

Tags: c, arrays

I'm still pretty new to coding so I'm having trouble with the syntax in this situation. How am I supposed to format this? Whenever I try to build the program, it says that there is an error:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ']' token
  assign_q(chess[][]);
```

There's no need for me to put all my code here, but here's a little snippet:

```
#define N 8

int chess[N][N] = {2}, l, m;

void assign_q(int chess[N][N]);

int main()
{
    int i, j;

    assign_q(chess[][]);
```

Comment: `assign_q(chess[][]);` --> `assign_q(chess);` or change void.

Answer (score 1):

In C, if you want to pass an array, you just have to do not have to use the `[]`-operator. The `[]`-operator is only for access to array-elements.

In your example `chess` is already of type `int [][]`, so there is no need to de-reference it.

However, you may not have to pass the array at all. If you declare the array at global scope as you have done it, you can access it directly from anywhere within the same compilation unit or another one by using `extern`.

Comment: I'll take a look at that, might simplify my program a bunch

Comment: Using a global variable is something you usually want to avoid though. So do look into the correct way to pass the array. Just for your first simple programs, it may help to use globals some time.

Comment: In this case I though it'd be best to use a global variable (im solving the eight queens puzzle). But i'm still getting syntax errors that I cant seem to figure out... I'm about to post my code asking for help, so hopefully I can get those errors figured out

Answer (score -1):

regarding this line:

```
assign_q(chess[][]);
```

What your trying to do is pass a pointer to the chess array

and in C, when an array name is referenced, it devolves to a pointer to that array;

so this will work.

```
assign_q(chess);
```

where assign_q will have a prototype of:

```
void assign_q( int * chess );
```

and a declaration of:

```
void assign_q( int * chess )
{
    int row;
    int column;
    ....
}
```

then access the chess array as:

```
chess[row][column]
```

Comment: cannot access as `chess[row][column]` if `int *chess`